# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim' when doing model.fit()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
def tf_data(path, batch_size=32):
    paths = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path)
    paths = paths.batch(64)
    dataset = paths.map(prepare_data, tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.unbatch()
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    return dataset   
data_train = tf_data('C:/Users/krajat/Desktop/New folder/FYP/New folder/output/train/*/*.jpg', batch_size)
data_test = tf_data('C:/Users/krajat/Desktop/New folder/FYP/New folder/output/test/*/*.jpg', batch_size)
```

data_train is of RepeatDataset Type.

```
history = model.fit(data_train,
                   epochs=5,
                   steps_per_epoch = p[0]//batch_size,
                   validation_data = data_test,
                   validation_steps = p[2]//batch_size,
                   callbacks=[cp, csv_logger, reduce_lr])
```

After running model.fit(), it throws an error :

```
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20152/1127474368.py in <module>

    ----> 1 history = model.fit(data_train,
          2                    epochs=5,
          3                    steps_per_epoch = p[0]//batch_size,
          4                    validation_data = data_test,
          5                    validation_steps = p[2]//batch_size,

> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)

> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in 

    quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
         52   try:
         53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
    ---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
         55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
         56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

> **UnknownError: Graph execution error:**

> **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'** Traceback (most recent call last):

>  File "C:\Users\krajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 271, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

>  File "C:\Users\krajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

>  File "C:\Users\krajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2113, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)

>  File "C:\Users\krajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2187, in _vectorize_call
    res = self._vectorize_call_with_signature(func, args)

>  File "C:\Users\krajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2242, in _vectorize_call_with_signature
    _update_dim_sizes(dim_sizes, result, core_dims)

>  File "C:\Users\krajat\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1841, in _update_dim_sizes
    if arg.ndim < num_core_dims:

> **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ndim'**


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_400484]
```

Comment: Some argument to `fit` is a number, int, when it should be a `numpy` array. Your debugging task is to verify the type of all arguments, and see that they match with the documented expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I got the mistake eventually.. but now got stuck in a incompatible shape error :(

Comment: Can you post an explanation on how you solved this issue? I am struggling with a similar problem